# Who to control browser level zoom that should work with all cross platform browser

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox, browser

**I am looking for JS script to control browser's zoom.**

*I have tried the `"document.body.style.zoom"`, but this doesn't work with Firefox.*

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser's zoom level cannot be controlled via JavaScript, fortunately. It's a user-controlled setting.<sup>[1]</sup>

The [`zoom` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) indeed does a similar thing - not only it scales the element but it also scales it's rendered size, affecting the page's layout. However, unlike changing the browser's zoom level, the `zoom` property does not affect media queries (tested on Chrome) so even if applied to the `<html>` or `<body>` element the result may be different than changing the browser's zoom. The other problem is that the `zoom` property is not standard and not supported cross-browsers.

An alternative is to apply a transformation like `transform: scale(2);` or `transform: scale(0.5);` . However transformations only change the element visually and not the rendered size, so you will need to handle that too. The following code seems to mimic a zoom level of 50% reasonably:

```
:root {
    width: 200%;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

<sup>[1]</sup> It can be controlled by browser extensions privileged JS, but that's out of question. There is also a [`<meta>` tag setting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) that controls zoom level but it's only for smartphones and can also be overriden by browser settings.

Comment: Hello Noam, thanks for the suggestion. I actually tried this and the output I'm getting with the same is not what I am looking for.

The output that I am looking for : [ https://ibb.co/1fYq9PQ ]
The out that I'm getting when trying "scale": [ https://ibb.co/VDt9jnF ]

Comment: I updated myu answer with more information, see if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Noam, your answer was helpful.